# Is there a constraint between two tables to ensure a number is contained by a range?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables like these (ignoring the rest of fields and constraints):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ...

    f1 UUID NOT NULL,
    f2 UUID NOT NULL,
    f3 UUID NOT NULL,
    the_range INT8RANGE NOT NULL,

    ...
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    ...

    g1 UUID NOT NULL,
    g2 UUID NOT NULL,
    g3 UUID NOT NULL,
    the_number INT8 NOT NULL,

    ...

    FOREIGN KEY (g1, g2, g3)
    REFERENCES table1 (f1, f2, f3)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,

    ...
);
```

I need a constraint that ensures `the_number <@ the_range` along with that `FOREIGN KEY`. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think there's a builtin way to do that, you'll need to use a trigger.

Comment: I thought about using redundancy instead of a trigger too, but I hope someone has a better solution.

Comment: Triggers to enforce constraints may require additional locking or higher transaction isolation level: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, up to now, is modifying `table2` like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    ...

    g1 UUID NOT NULL,
    g2 UUID NOT NULL,
    g3 UUID NOT NULL,
    the_range INT8RANGE NOT NULL,
    the_number INT8 NOT NULL,

    ...

    FOREIGN KEY (g1, g2, g3, the_range)
    REFERENCES table1 (f1, f2, f3, the_range)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,

    CHECK (the_number <@ the_range),

    ...
);
```

In this way, when you update `the_range` in `table1`, you'll change `table2`'s `the_range` too. It's a redundancy mechanism that repeats the range in order to allow the check; it requires more space, but I prefer this over triggers.

I don't know if this is the best/safest way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility of solution with a function used in a table constraint: the function takes `the_number` and the foreign key as parameters; the function returns true if it finds a matching row in `table1` otherwise it return false.

Here is a simplified example:

```
create table table1( 
 key1 int primary key, 
 the_range int8range not null
);
create table table2(
 the_number int8 not null, 
 fkey2 int references table1
);
--
create or replace function checkn(p_key int8, p_number int8) returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 v int; 
begin
 select key1 into v 
 from table1 
 where key1 = p_key and p_number <@ the_range; 
 if v is not null
 then return true;
 else return false;
 end if;
end;
$$;
--
alter table table2 add constraint fcheck check (checkn(fkey2, the_number));
```

Some testing:

```
create table table1( 
 key1 int primary key, 
 the_range int8range not null
);
CREATE TABLE

create table table2(
 the_number int8 not null, 
 fkey2 int references table1
);
CREATE TABLE

create or replace function checkn(p_key int8, p_number int8) returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 v int; 
begin
 select key1 into v 
 from table1 
 where key1 = p_key and p_number <@ the_range; 
 if v is not null
 then return true;
 else return false;
 end if;
end;
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION

alter table table2 add constraint fcheck check (checkn(fkey2, the_number));
ALTER TABLE

insert into table1(key1, the_range) values (1, '[10,20]');
INSERT 0 1

insert into table1(key1, the_range) values (2, '[20,30]');
INSERT 0 1

select * from table1;
 key1 | the_range 
------+-----------
    1 | [10,21)
    2 | [20,31)
(2 rows)

insert into table2(the_number, fkey2) values(9, 1);
ERROR:  new row for relation "table2" violates check constraint "fcheck"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, 1).

insert into table2(the_number, fkey2) values(21, 2);
INSERT 0 1

update table2 set the_number=33 where fkey2=2;
new row for relation "table2" violates check constraint "fcheck"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (33, 2).

select * from table2;
 the_number | fkey2 
------------+-------
         21 |     2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Unlike a foreign key (or suitable triggers), this will however not complain about a change in `table1` breaking the constraint.

Comment: As @Bergi said, it breaks consistency. Try this to see it: `UPDATE table1 SET the_range = '[23,30]' WHERE key1 = 2;`